# What do I put in my python oauth2 POST headers?

Tags: python, header, request, oauth-2.0

Here is my current code to do a POST in python using oauth2.  For the life of me, I cannot get past the 401 error, and I think it might have something to do with my headers.  I am just pasting my headers in here as they print out, as I have used another routine to generate them with myheaders=req.to_header().  This should show you what's really in there.  What looks wrong?  Please help!

```
def post_or_put_me(myaction,myxml,myurl):
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'my_admin_access'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxx'
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = oauth2.Token(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
    myheaders = {'Authorization': 'OAuth realm="",oauth_body_hash="xxxxxxxx",oauth_nonce="84691521", oauth_timestamp="1351179163",oauth_consumer_key="my_admin_access",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxx"'}
    xml_string = ElementTree.tostring(myxml)
    data = urllib.urlencode({'xml': xml_string})

    resp, content = client.request(
        myurl,
        method=myaction,
        body=data,
        headers = myheaders,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the 2-legged oauth2 POST/PUT builds its own headers; I do not have to populate them, except for the Content-Type (in my case).  See the answer supplied here for full details of how to do both a 2-legged GET and a 2-legged POST/PUT: [How do I send a POST using 2-legged oauth2 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977604/how-do-i-send-a-post-using-2-legged-oauth2-in-python/13167178#13167178).