# Is 2 legged oauth possible with Rauth or alternative python 3 library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, oauth-1.0a, 2-legged

I have been searching for a way to implement 2 legged oauth in python 3 to work with the brightcloud api. They offer several code examples using java, php, ruby, .NET C# here: https://bcws.brightcloud.com/code-samples.php. I tried following the same logic to convert the java example into python, however, I'm relatively new to python and I quickly came unstuck.

I have tried implementing using rauth, however, the basic setup utilises a request_token_url which is not provided by brightcloud. I also tried implementing with the following code which was based on this answer -
 [How do I send a POST using 2-legged oauth2 in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977604/how-do-i-send-a-post-using-2-legged-oauth2-in-python)

```
import oauth2 
import urllib #for url-encode
import urllib.request
import time #Unix timestamp import oauth2

# construct request url
base_url = "http://thor.brightcloud.com/rest"
uri_info_path = "/uris"
url = urllib.parse.quote_plus("http://www.booking.com")

# api key and secret
consumer_key = 'MY_CONSUMER_KEY'
consumer_secret = 'MY_CONSUMER_SECRET'

# contruct endpoint
endpoint = rest_endpoint + uri_info_path + '/' + url

# build request
def build_request(url, method):
    params = {                                            
        'oauth_version': "1.0",
        'oauth_nonce': oauth2.generate_nonce(),
        'oauth_timestamp': int(time.time())
    }
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)
    params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key
    req = oauth2.Request(method=method, url=url, parameters=params)
    signature_method = oauth2.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, None)
    return req

# call
request = build_request(endpoint,'GET')
u = urllib.request.urlopen(request.to_url())
data = u.read()
print (data)
```

There is a problem with this line:
    u = urllib.request.urlopen(request.to_url())

Which generates the following traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "bright.py", line 37, in 
>      u = urllib.request.urlopen(request.to_url())
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
>      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
>      response = meth(req, response)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
>      'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
>      return self._call_chain(*args)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
>      result = func(*args)
>    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in >http_error_default
>      raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: any solution here?  Looking for this exact thing.