# How to do http request's POST to an API with Oauth2 in Python

Tags: python, api, post, oauth, authorization

I've been trying to figure out how to do POST in an API (in this case Goodreads's) using [ouath2 library](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2), but I keep stumbling to a dead end since the output is always an error message.

I refer to the answers in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977604/how-do-i-send-a-post-using-2-legged-oauth2-in-python).

[Below](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#author_following.create)'s the Goodread's API documentation I'm currently working on.

> **Follow an author**   
> Make the signed-in user follow an author using OAuth. You'll need to register your app (required).  URL:
>   https://www.goodreads.com/author_followings?id=AUTHOR_ID&format=xml
>   
> HTTP method: POST

**below is my 1st POST attempt:** (error msg: *not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object*)

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/author_followings?'
parameters = {'id' : '1077326',
              'format' : 'xml',
             }
echo_base_url = url + urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key ='J9l5Jsn...........', secret='N8cWf4Da...bynGVQ..........')
client = oauth.Client(consumer)

resp, content = client.request(
                echo_base_url,
                method = "POST",
                body= urllib.parse.urlencode(None),
                headers= None,
                force_auth_header=True,
                )
print (resp, content)
```

**my 2nd attempt:** (error msg: *request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_auth_header'*)

```
import oauth2 as oauth, urllib.parse

def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="POST", post_body=None, http_headers=None):
    CONSUMER_KEY = key
    CONSUMER_SECRET = secret
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    #token = oauth.Token(key=key, secret=secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer)
    resp, content = client.request(
        url,
        method=http_method,
        body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'status': post_body}),
        headers=http_headers,
        force_auth_header=True,
    )
    return content

oauth_req('https://www.goodreads.com/author_followings?id=1077326&format=xml', 'J9l5.......', 'N8........QYIg70ru.......FVoYc', http_method="POST", post_body=None, http_headers=None)
```

I can only do GET so far and have been trying on POST but haven't found any code that works even once. Need an enlightenment here..

Answer (score -1):

Use an API tool and get results from it first: Curl, SOAPUI, etc...
After getting proper POST request results, move those data into your code.

---

for the first error message one of the array's is in an improper format - parameters, request or response.