# Not Authorized error POST request using oauth2 python

Tags: python, api, twitter, oauth, urllib

Instead of using library for specific API access use (i.e. TwitterSearch library, etc), I want to understand the API request and response coding concept as fundamental as possible.

From [this thread's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977604/how-do-i-send-a-post-using-2-legged-oauth2-in-python) I found that there's this [oauth2 library](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2) that I can use.

I have already implemented it for Twitter's POST and GET API access methods through [this example](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/wiki/Examples) provided and successfully built it myself.

When I tried to implement the same method to Goodreads's API from the Twitter API code I built, it's successful for the GET method but not for the POST one.

Below are the Goodreads API codes along with the Twitter ones which I used as reference.

**Twitter GET:**

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time, ssl, json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json'
params = {
    'oauth_version': "1.0",
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'count': '3',
}

token = oauth.Token(key="75230340-cwrB.......", secret="OUsh3xgdZ.........IfIDiy")
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="gmW4......Oh4tV", secret="S9c5J3.....unbUTL")

# Set our token/key parameters
params['oauth_token'] = token.key
params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

# Create our request. Change method, etc. accordingly.
req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)

# Sign the request.
signature_method = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
req.sign_request(signature_method, consumer, token)
url_final = req.to_url()

#url request
print('\nRetrieving', url_final, '\n')
connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url_final, context=ctx)
data = connection.read().decode('utf-8')

js = json.loads(data)
jsdmp = json.dumps(js, indent=2)
print(jsdmp)
```

**Goodreads GET:**

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time, ssl, json
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json'
params = {
    'oauth_version': "1.0",
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'isbns': '9780439785969,0596009208,0596517742',
    'format': 'json',
}

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="J9l.......cpgzg", secret="N8cW.....xrXF1V2uqFVoYc")
params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

req = oauth.Request(method="GET", url=url, parameters=params)
url_final = req.to_url()

print('\nRetrieving', url_final, '\n')
connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url_final, context=ctx)
data = connection.read().decode('utf-8')

js = json.loads(data)
jsdmp = json.dumps(js, indent=2)
print(jsdmp, '\n')
```

Above Goodreads' GET works well which I tried to implement based on previous Twitter's GET.

But below Goodreads' POST doesnt work out and shows 'Not Authorized' message from *print(content)* in *client.request()*

**Twitter's POST:**

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time, ssl
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json'
params = {
    'oauth_version': "1.0",
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'status': 'hello, it\'s me',
}

token = oauth.Token(key="75230340-cw.............iNsP35Eq", secret="OUsh3.....IDiy")
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="gmW4b....h4tV", secret="S9c5J3O....unbUTL")
params['oauth_token'] = token.key
params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
resp, content = client.request(
    url,
    method='POST',
    body=urllib.parse.urlencode(params),
)
print(resp, '\n\n ***BORDER*** \n\n', content)
```

**Goodreads' POST:**

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time, ssl
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/author_followings'
params = {
    'oauth_version': "1.0",
    'oauth_nonce': oauth.generate_nonce(),
    'oauth_timestamp': str(int(time.time())),
    'id': '1077326',
    'format': 'xml',
}

consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="J9l5JsnPR...gzg", secret="N8cWf4Da03.....qFVoYc")
params['oauth_consumer_key'] = consumer.key

client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(
    url,
    method='POST',
    body=urllib.parse.urlencode(params),
)
print(resp, '\n\n ***BORDER*** \n\n', content)
```

I'm rather confused isn't it sopposed to be already authorized since I have already used:

```
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
resp, content = client.request(
    url,
    method='POST',
    body=urllib.parse.urlencode(params),
)
```

..in Goodreads' POST code above? Is it the parameter to decide the authorization?

[This](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#author_following.create) is the documentation for this Goodreads' POST I'm working on

Comment: I'm confused here, are you attempting to POST a new status (Tweet) using only OAuth2 application context? that cannot work. You need a user context, and Twitter only supports OAuth 1.0A for that.

Comment: @AndyPiper The library is actually in Oauth 1.0, oauth2 is only the name of the library based on [here](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2). Posting new status on Twitter API is already successful, but then I want to implement the POST method used in Twitter for Goodreads API's POST (code attached above) but it doesn't work and I wonder why.. The aim of my work here is I want to find out the basic code to use for POST and GET as reference in all API web services use. I think I have figured out GET, what left is POST

Comment: So this is a Goodreads API issue? Ok.